# More Odd MySQL Behavior - Query Optimization Help

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

We have a central login that we use to support multiple websites. To store our users' data we have an `accounts` table which stores each user account and then `users` tables for each site for site specific information. We also have a simple `connections` table which stores the connections between users.

We noticed that one query that is joining the tables on their primary key `user_id` is executing slowly. I'm hoping that some SQL expert out there can explain why it's using `WHERE` to search the users_site1 table and suggest how we can optimize it. Here is the slow query & the explain results:

```
mysql> explain select a.username,a.first_name,a.last_name,a.organization_name,a.organization,a.city,a.state,a.zip,a.country,a.profile_photo,a.facebook_id,a.twitter_id,u.reviews from accounts a join users_site1 u ON a.user_id=u.user_id where a.user_id IN (select cid2 from connections where cid1=10001006 AND type="MM" AND status="A") OR a.user_id IN (select cid1 from connections where cid2=10001006 AND type="MM" AND status="A") order by RAND() LIMIT 4;
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table       | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | u           | ALL    | PRIMARY           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                  | 79783 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a           | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY | 4       | exampledb.u.user_id |     1 |                                              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | connections | ref    | PRIMARY,cid1,cid2 | cid2    | 6       | const,const           |     2 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | connections | ref    | PRIMARY,cid1,cid2 | cid1    | 6       | const,const           |     1 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here are the definitions for each table:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `user_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_id` bigint(15) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_username` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_photo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suffix_name` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `province` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(11,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(12,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `about_me` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activities` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referrer` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `referredid` int(9) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `verify` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT 'R',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `network` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `logins` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `api_logins` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `private` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `facebook_id` (`facebook_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `state` (`state`)
);

CREATE TABLE `users_site1` (
  `user_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `facebook_id` bigint(15) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_username` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_publish` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_checkin` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_offline` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_id` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_secret` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_username` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` char(1) DEFAULT 'M',
  `referrer` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `referredid` int(9) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `session` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `api_session` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT 'R',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `logins` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `api_logins` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `connections` (
  `cid1` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cid2` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cid3` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid1`,`cid2`,`type`,`cid3`),
  KEY `cid1` (`cid1`,`type`),
  KEY `cid2` (`cid2`,`type`)
);
```

Comment: Please append [query profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) result, it's more intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `WHERE a.userid IN( ... ) OR a.userid IN( ... )` you should use another join:

```
select 
a.username,a.first_name,a.last_name,a.organization_name,a.organization,a.city,
a.state,a.zip,a.country,a.profile_photo,a.facebook_id,a.twitter_id,u.reviews 
from accounts a 
join users_site1 u ON a.user_id=u.user_id 
join ( select cid2 as id from connections 
       where cid1=10001006 AND type="MM" AND status="A"
       union
       select cid1 as id from connections
       where cid2=10001006 AND type="MM" AND status="A" ) c
on a.user_id = c.id
order by RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: + oned. This _and_ decomposing the select and where in 2 distinct queries would help a lot on perfomance, I feel.

Comment: Wow! I have to say I'm not easily impressed but that rewrite of the query is damn impressive. Worked like a charm. I didn't even know you could do a join like that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried remove `order by RAND()` and run again?

my result is below:

```
+----+--------------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table       | type           | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a           | ALL            | PRIMARY           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 2    | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | u           | ALL            | PRIMARY           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 2    | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | connections | index_subquery | PRIMARY,cid1,cid2 | PRIMARY | 14      | func,const,const | 1    | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | connections | ref            | PRIMARY,cid1,cid2 | PRIMARY | 14      | const,func,const | 1    | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have and it doesn't effect the query at all. The issue seems to be related to the join between the accounts and users_site1 table. Any other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: @russell-c I have tested on my local, It's different like your result. What's your MySql version? btw, table `accounts` miss column `twitter_id`, table `users_site1` miss column `reviews`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a MySQL guru by any means but been have involved more than once in optimization of high performance applications, though I was more on the implementation end of the optimisation process versus finding what needed to be optimized.

The firt thing I see is the subqueries seem efficient, but the way the first query is run with this where clause: ...  where a.user_id IN (select cid2 ...) or a.user_id IN (select cid1 from ...)   is a performance killer in my very humble opinion.

The first thing I would try to optimise performance, consider trying *join decomposition* , split your request in 2 or even 3 queries. The code is less pretty, but the db will be able to work more efficiently. It is a myth that doing everything in one query is better.

What can this bring you? Caching will be more efficient, if using MyISam tables the locking srategy is more efficient when you have less tables in your query, and you will reduce the redundant row accesses. If you can get your main query ( that would be the last one if you decompose ) from Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort, you will have much faster response.

Profile the different options you try with SHOW SESSION STATUS and FLUSH status, also you can disable caching to get true comparison of different options you try by adding SQL_NO_CACHE in your query, ie SELSECT SQL_NO_CACHE a.username ... etc..

Profiling and measuring the results is the only way you will be able to determine the performance gains. Unfortunately this step is often overlooked.

Good luck!